# How to use XG-Boost with PySPARK

Tags: python, pyspark, xgboost

Can anyone recommend any solution of how to use XGBoost with PySpark specifically not the Spark-Scala,
Secondly does XGBoost will boost the performance if used with Pyspark or not?

Mainly am doing feature engineering and ML model training on spark so am want to boost performance.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602317/how-to-use-xgboost-in-pyspark-pipeline

Comment: @Bitswazsky I have already seen this thread earlier and it doesn't have the correct answer to my question. The link given in the answer also doesn't work anymore.